# Can a child text box grow with parent rectangle in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008, sql-server-data-tools

I have a rectangle with 2 subreports in it.  I am trying to have a "header" text box to the left of the two reports that grows with the rectangle so that the "header" stays centered with the content. [Current Arrangement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JN11J.png)

[Desired Arrangement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nl0qO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you have constructed the table/rectangles but this should work...

There is almost certainly a better way of doing this but this does work...

First insert a table. Delete the last two columns so you only have a single column left.

[image]

Then Delete the header row, you'll have a single cell remaining.

Now go to the Row Groups at the bottom of the screen, click the drop down and choose, "Add Group" --> "Parent Group".

[image]

In the dialogue, type 1 in the Group by field (this is just a dummy value) and select "Add group header". Click OK.

[image]

Optionally, you can right-click the details group and delete it. Select Delete Group Only when prompted.

[image]

Now the left column is merged so you can put your header text in there and set Vertical Align to "Middle". Add you sub reports as required and it will always be centred. Sere's some examples with different sized sub reports.

[image]

[image]

and finally with the text rotated which if your header is short and be formatted in a large enough font, sometimes looks better.

[image]

I left the ugly border in place so you can see the positioning more clearly.

Comment: This answer worked great.  It resolved issues I had with formatting that I did not even mention.

Answer (score 0):

Create a table with two cells. Your header cell on the left and a blank cell on the right. Then create a second table with your data. Drag and drop it into the blank cell.

The grouping in the parent cell will apply to the child cell in the table. The parent table's dataset will override a different dataset in the child table (which I doubt will cause any concern for you).

To make it look right you will want to remove the outside borders of the child table.